# Debug (MetalScen) SceneKit EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, exc-bad-access

Hi I'm trying to put together a panorama view that react to motion  and touch using [MetalScen](https://github.com/ejeinc/MetalScope), you can change the the panorama image by selection from a collection view.

the problem is sometimes the app crash randomly when I choose new image, it happens randomly but I noticed it happens more often if I switch between images to quick. 
the crash that I get is

```
SceneKit`C3DModelValueStoragePrepareNextFrame: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

see image 
[thread crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJpGZ.png)

[Here is the project on GitHub](https://github.com/turk-jk/panorama.git) (needs a pod install), any help or clues are appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after long battle and fight with the code and search through the web, this for any person has the same problem

I found that :

The panorama View `(SCNScene)` where I'm changing the image rapidly. was on a strong reference and that for some reason ( I don't know , please inform me ) caused the **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** crash, I changed it to weak reference in the declaration, and it's pretty smooth and no crashes